# Godog Undefined Steps when Steps are present

Tags: go, testing, visual-studio-code, cucumber, bdd

I've been implementing feature file tests for a microservice in Golang using Godog.

There are 54 steps in my feature file and I generated the step definitions for all of them.

When I run the test using `go test` command, the first 22 scenarios pass and the 23 is declared as `Undefined` even though its definition is present.

My Console output after any test:

```
......................U------------------------U-----U 54


1 scenarios (1 undefined)
54 steps (22 passed, 3 undefined, 29 skipped)
44.0003ms

Randomized with seed: 1621922954984294500

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

func readingResourceOfId(arg1 string) error {
        return godog.ErrPending
}

func resourceWithIdIsFound(arg1 string) error {
        return godog.ErrPending
}

func resourceWithIdIsNotFound(arg1 string) error {
        return godog.ErrPending
}

func InitializeScenario(ctx *godog.ScenarioContext) {
        ctx.Step(`^reading resource of id "([^"]*)"$`, readingResourceOfId)
        ctx.Step(`^resource with id "([^"]*)" is found$`, resourceWithIdIsFound)
        ctx.Step(`^resource with id "([^"]*)" is not found$`, resourceWithIdIsNotFound)
}

testing: warning: no tests to run
PASS
ok      gitlab.com/xxxxxx/go-micro-service      0.595s
```

Here are snippets from my `main_test.go` file

```
func InitializeScenario(ctx *godog.ScenarioContext) {

api := &apiFeature{
    Set: make(map[string]interface{}),
}

ctx.Step(`^API response code is (\d+)$`, api.aPIResponseCodeIs)
ctx.Step(`^API response Location header is "([^"]*)" with "([^"]*)" autogenerated$`, api.aPIResponseLocationHeaderIsWithAutogenerated)
ctx.Step(`^creating a resource with name "([^"]*)" and type "([^"]*)"$`, api.creatingAResourceWithNameAndType)
ctx.Step(`^deleting the resource of id "([^"]*)"$`, api.deletingTheResourceOfId)
ctx.Step(`^external resource id (\d+) is "([^"]*)"$`, api.externalResourceIdIs)
ctx.Step(`^finally setting reference to external resource (\d+) on id "([^"]*)"$`, api.finallySettingReferenceToExternalResourceOnId)
ctx.Step(`^id is "([^"]*)"$`, api.idIs)
ctx.Step(`^modifying resource of id "([^"]*)" setting status to "([^"]*)"$`, api.modifyingResourceOfIdSettingStatusTo)
ctx.Step(`^name is "([^"]*)"$`, api.nameIs)
ctx.Step(`^searching for resource instances$`, api.searchingForResourceInstances)
ctx.Step(`^setting reference to external resource (\d+) on id "([^"]*)"$`, api.settingReferenceToExternalResourceOnId)
ctx.Step(`^status end date is null$`, api.statusEndDateIsNull)
ctx.Step(`^status is "([^"]*)"$`, api.statusIs)
ctx.Step(`^status "([^"]*)" is found in history$`, api.statusIsFoundInHistory)
ctx.Step(`^status start date is not null$`, api.statusStartDateIsNotNull)
ctx.Step(`^the micro-service is started$`, api.theMicroserviceIsStarted)
ctx.Step(`^type is "([^"]*)"$`, api.typeIs)


//Steps are defined
ctx.Step(`^reading resource of id "([^"]*)"$`, api.readingResourceOfId)
ctx.Step(`^resource with id "([^"]*)" is found$`, api.resourceWithIdIsFound)
ctx.Step(`^resource with id "([^"]*)" is not found$`, api.resourceWithIdIsNotFound)
}
```

Can anyone point out what is the issue behind this, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out Godog doesn't trim the Steps from the `feature` files.

So, In my feature files, the steps for the above lines included:

When reading resource of id "ID1"_____(blank space)

The regex pattern therefore wasn't able to map the step definitions to these lines for some reason.

As soon as I removed the empty spaces, it worked great.